# Rotate a list in prolog recursively

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to rotate a list in prolog recursively but it does not work as expected.

Code:

```
rot([],[]).
rot([H|T1], [T2|H]):-rot(T1,T2).
```

Output:

```
?- rot([1,2,3], V).
V = [[[[]|3]|2]|1]
```

Expected output:

```
?- rot([1,2,3], V).
V = [3,2,1]
```

Could anyone explain me why my code does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Prolog is untyped, you can indeed write something like `[List|Element]`, but if you want a list to make sense, the only way you can construct lists is like `[Element|List]`. So `[T2|H]` does not make sense at all. In that case `T2` should be an element, and `H` a list (or the empty list `[]`).

You will need to define two predicates:

- the main predicate (`rot/2`) that simply pops the head from the given list and calls the recursive predicate; and
- the recursive predicate (here `rot/3`) that simply passes all elements of the given list and emits the original head as tail element.

Together this works like:

```
%main predicate rot/2
rot([],[]).
rot([H|T1],T2) :-
    rot(T1,H,T2).

%recursive predicate rot/3
rot([],Last,[Last]).
rot([H|T1],Last,[H|T2]) :-
    rot(T1,Last,T2).
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work because in an expression like `[H|T]`, `H` is an element of the list and `T` is the tail of the list--also a list. For instance:

```
?- [H|T] = [1,2,3].
H = 1,
T = [2, 3].
```

So what happens when you switch that around?

```
?- [H|T] = [1,2,3], X = [T|H].
H = 1,
T = [2, 3],
X = [[2, 3]|1].
```

See the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the second clause. What I do is to rotate the tail of the first list inside L1 and then call `append` with L1 and the first element and assign the result to L (the second argument)

```
my-append([], L, L).
my-append([H|T], L, [H|R]) :- my-append(T, L, R).

rot([], []).
rot([H|T], L) :- rot(T, L1), my-append(L1, H, L).
```

Comment: You are defining clauses of the form `-(my, append([], L, L))`.